# Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Tags: angular

I am trying to learn angular but I am stuck while trying to put the value from response to a local variable.

My data from Server Looks like :

```
[{text : 'Some text', owner: 'Tim'}, {text : 'second Message', owner : 'Jane'}]
```

This is my service :

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class WebService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getMessages():Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:1234/messages');
    }
}
```

And this is my component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { WebService } from './web.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'messages',
    template: `
    <div *ngFor="let message of messages">
        <mat-card style="margin:8px">
            <mat-card-title>{{message.owner}}</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-content>{{message.text}}</mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
    `
})
export class MessagesComponent {
    constructor(private webService : WebService) {}

    async ngOnInit() {
        var response = await this.webService.getMessages();
        this.messages = response.json();
    }

    messages = [];
}
```

I have tried several other things like map and subscribe but none of them seems to work. I have tried almost all the examples from the internet but always having an issue. Please, somebody, explain.

Answer (score 1):

async / await doesn't mix with observables. rxjs usage is like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.webService.getMessages().subscribe(response => {
      this.messages = response.json();
    })
}
```

Comment: Best practice would be to expose the observable to the template and use an async pipe like *ngFor="let message of messages$ | async"

Comment: Yup. Would be. And moving the .json call to the service inside a map operator or better yet getting upgraded past angular 4 to use the httpclient

Answer (score 0):

Using best practices expose the observable to the template and let Angular handle subscribe/unsubscribe behind the scenes using the async pipe.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { WebService } from './web.service'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'messages',
    template: `
    <div *ngFor="let message of messages$ | async">
        <mat-card style="margin:8px">
            <mat-card-title>{{message.owner}}</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-content>{{message.text}}</mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
    `
})
export class MessagesComponent {

   messages$: Observable<any>;

   constructor(private webService : WebService) {}

   ngOnInit() {
        this.messages$ = this.webService.getMessages();
    }
}
```

Taking the suggestion above also do this in your service

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class WebService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getMessages():Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:1234/messages').pipe(
            map(x => x.json())
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: definitely best practices here. but the only note for OP if they try to implement this, is that since they're using the deprecated Http module, we're likely in angular 4 or earlier here which probably means rxjs before pipeable operators were a thing. OP should upgrade and use `rxjs-compat` to migrate ASAP, but the operator style at this point was more like `http.get('url').map(x => x.json())`